# What's it called when you make an adjective post-positive?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, word-order, hyperbaton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some adjectives follow the nouns they modify?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/42319/10041)

In English, adjectives usually precede the nouns they describe, as in "organic carrots".

However, in some cases "normal" adjectives are reversed - possibly for emphasis or to add an exotic flair.

For example, Curtis Mayfield's album "A Love Supreme"; this would normally flow "a supreme love", but is reversed for some reason.

Whatever the case may be, is there a word for this switcharound?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do some adjectives follow the nouns they modify?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/42319/10041)

Comment: @drɱ65δ Ah, awesome. I will edit my question a bit with the new term to be clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called *hyperbaton*, which means to use the words out of their normal order. This can be used as an impact strategy. The writing guide *Bang: Writing with Impact* explains it this way:

> Any time you place words out of their normal order, you create impact.
>   You force the reader to pay attention to them, reflect on them, and
>   remember them. In this strategy, you immediately follow the name of a
>   thing with an adjective or descriptive phrase. In this way, the
>   description becomes part of the name of the thing; they are
>   inseparable. When your reader thinks of the thing, he or she will also
>   think of the description because the description becomes part of the
>   name.
>
> Your reader will notice this immediately, which means this strategy
>   can be used to emphasize a key characteristic. However, because this
>   change in word order is so obvious and so prone to sounding contrived,
>   it must be used carefully and infrequently. In the right place, it can
>   be a highly effective technique for emphasizing a point. Use it at the
>   end of a sentence for greatest impact.
>
> “This is a **plan impossible**.”

Comment: I think you may have answered this as I was editing the question, but it's spot on either way - thank you!