# The thing proper

Tags: adjectives, word-order, postpositive

I found myself writing this:

> .. and this is before we consider *mathematics proper*.

It seemed like a natural kind of thing to write, but I couldn't find an example of it. I get the impression it's OK to use it in this way; to mean the major mathematical schools in this case (rather than people who just do mathematics).

Is there any objection to this?

Comment: related: [What does “proper” mean in this context?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46407/what-does-proper-mean-in-this-context)

Answer (score 8):

It is grammatically correct but does not mean mathematical schools. It means mathematics in the most strict, literal sense.

If by *major mathematical schools* you mean major mathematical philosophies or major groups of people who share a mathematical philosophy (such as [those listed at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics#Contemporary_schools_of_thought)), then one alternative would be:

> … and this is before we consider *major mathematical schools of thought*.

Comment: the field of mathematics proper. I guess then! hmmmm... the field of proper mathematics is clearly wrong. the proper field of mathematics is a wrong too (for my context). field proper of mathematics?

Comment: Does my edit help?

Comment: As it happens, no, but you would have needed to have the rest of the sentence to know that. I mean mathematicians whose job it is to be mathematicians, rather than scientists or philosophers i.e. defined by profession not disposition. I guess what I just written makes it write quite clear how I should change it. Thankyou for chipping in.

Comment: In that case change “mathematics proper” to “mathematicians proper” and that ought to express what you mean.

Answer (score 6):

There is no objection. *Proper* is one of the postpositive adjectives. Others are seen in phrases such as *heir apparent*, *devil incarnate*, *body politic*. See Wikipedia's page for more examples: [Postpositive adjectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-positive_adjective)

Answer (score 0):

"but I couldn't find an example of it"

In an introduction to Dante's *The Divine Comedy* the author says: " ... owing to the distinction between bestial malice and malice proper".