# Use of "Proper" as a postpositive adjective

Tags: adjectives, postpositive

I have an inkling that the following word usage is grammatically-correct; however, it is immensely difficult to search for confirmation, as all I receive for queries like "Proper as an adjective" are reams of results on "Proper adjectives". The word itself I am using as a postpositive adjective, similar in form to the phrase "time immemorial".

> The shelter remains in name only; the shelter proper is in another town.
>
> Work in theory remained, although operations proper had mostly been outsourced.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Some previous discussion [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42319/why-do-some-adjectives-follow-the-nouns-they-modify).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perfectly grammatical.

The OED, s.v. **proper**, *a.*, definition 7.c, says:

> c. Strictly or accurately so called; in the strict use of the word; genuine, real. In later use freq. as postmodifier.

The earliest example of this use that it quotes is 1807: "The earths proper do not unite with oxygen... Characters of the alkaline and proper earths."

Comment: Postpositioning *proper* in this way reminds me of using a postpositioned *-self/selves* pronoun following a noun as an intensifier.

Comment: I don't recognise that, @tchrist: can you give an example?

Comment: @ColinFine I think tchrist may have been referring to a sentence such as "He picked the berries *himself*."

Comment: Thanks, @pyobum. I don't think that is what tchrist meant, but has led me to realise he is probably talking about phrases like "the house itself".

Comment: @ColinFine Ah, right!!