# How is "proper" used in "the building proper"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

> "The building proper is a tall, four-storey, masonry oval – a great bowl slung from outer rings of stacked barrel vaults."

What does the word "proper" mean in this sentence? Is it an adjective, or adverb?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That post asks about the grammaticality. This one asks for part of speech and meaning.

Comment: @Cascabel Do you claim that Colin Fine's answer there isn't also the answer here?

Comment: Answered at [Use of "Proper" as a postpositive adjective](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/354077/use-of-proper-as-a-postpositive-adjective).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was not completely happy with it as an answer to this one. It did not address the issue of part of speech. "adjective-adverb?" was only mentioned in the title of the question.

Comment: @Cascabel No; Colin Fine's answer quotes OED's specification as adjective.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You mean the "a..," indicates it is an adjective? I had to look 3 times to find it.

Comment: @Cascabel The definitions given by OED (genuine, real) are confirmatory. If the question here is merely asking about POS and meaning, that renders it unacceptable on lack-of-research grounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Proper](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proper)** means the building alone, not other structures like a garage or garden on the site: The **building strictly by itself**.

Adjective definition 5. Being within the strictly limited sense, as of a term designating something: the town proper, excluding the suburbs.

Comment: Curiously, in  mathematics a proper divisor of a number is any divisor of the number other than the number itself.