# What are the grammatical rules for phrases like "Rome Victorious"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Some people seem to use this phrase. The adjective 'Victorious' seems that it is being used as if it is part of the noun.

Would this work in other cases? e.g. "Rome Sacrosanct".

Is it technically correct English?

Comment: Postpositive adjectives: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective

Comment: Yes, it's proper English. You see it with the noun "Rome" there because adjectives in Latin, the language of Ancient Rome, usually come after the noun they describe. That particular construction is a tip of the hat to Latin for the noun being Latin-related, i.e., "Rome."  Using non-restrictive adjectives postpositively in English is uncommon, but because of English grammarians spending centuries trying to make English more like Latin, it's not grammatically incorrect. Generally speaking, constructions that are grammatical in Latin are also grammatical in English, albeit sometimes stilted.

Comment: There's a great discussion from 2011 in this stack: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/42319/299777